# Simple form association label with image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to display the image on the gift on simple form association

I tried this code using `label_method` but it does not work:

```
<%=f.association :gift, :collection=> Gift.all, :label_method=>lambda { |gift| "#{gift.name}  #{image_tag 'gift.photo.url(:small)'}" }, :value_method=> :id, :as=>:radio_buttons%>
```

Comment: Provide the full form code in detail.

Comment: the form is simple_form for rails ,,what I need is how to get image_tag 'gift.photo.url(:small) giving me the image ..not the markup of it ..using rails ...I tried html_safe but not working with me

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem maybe consider accepting my answer

Answer (score 1):

This code can help you, show check boxes with images

```
<%= f.association :gift,
             :as => :check_boxes,
             item_wrapper_tag: :div,
             item_wrapper_class: "image-select",
             :collection => Gift.all,
             :label => false,
             :inline_label => false,
             :include_blank => false,
             :input_html => {multiple: true},
             :label_method => lambda { |b| image_tag(b.photo.url) },
             value_method: :id
           %>
```

Don't forget to use html_safe if you are working with string